# How to connect local java service to remote kubernetes services

Tags: eclipse, kubernetes, service-discovery, kube-dns

I am working as DevOps engineer on Kubernetes and spring cloud micro-services.

The problem I am asking about is if I have a development environment that runs some micro-services on kubernetes cluster (micro-services can interconnect each other using kube-dns) and I have some other micro-services running locally (which developer works on in eclipse IDE) in order to make some tests.

These micro-services running locally need to join the other ones running on the cluster to do the exact job. How may I resolve that issue?

Comment: In principle, your local Java service needs to make API calls to a remote service. Does your remote service also need to make API calls to your local Java service that is a WIP?

Comment: @iamnat, yes it does. But what you mean by WIP ?

Comment: I meant work-in-progress :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this : expose the services you need to connect to to the public (NodePort/LB/Ingress) or make it possible for the developers to actually reach inside your cluster so they can connect to these services.

The first one should be easy with something like NginX IngressController and vhost based exposing of services (you can also protect them with ie. basic auth).

The second one can be done with ie. Weave Net (if that is/can be the overlay network you use).  If you connect your devs to the central k8s cluster like this, they will only need to run kube-proxy on their nodes and point containers to k8s DNS. Obviously this is something I would advise only in case of dev/stage clusters and not for prod.

Comment: i want to take advantage from kube-dns running inside my k8s cluster. i prefer to deal with the second solution. i am running Flannel as overlay network. so how may i do it ?

Comment: with flannel it will be a bit more cumbersome as you need to first establish a secure channel (flannel is not encrypted) with some kind of VPN, make sure all nodes can route via vpn and only then launch flannel on the external machine and link it to your k8s flannel

Comment: thanks for your response. May you tell me how to do that ? tell me about all needed steps or give me, if you have, some useful links

Comment: Note that my dev env is running under windows whereas my kubernetes cluster is running on Centos7

Comment: @Pierre Besson, can you provide me a complete example about how running insecure (without TLS) ingress controller and resource with nginx to have remote access to services running inside kubernetes cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the kubernetes port forwarding to access a service in the kubernetes network from your local host during development. Once port forwarding is setup, alter the source code in the service that must access the other service on the kubernetes network during development time

To find your POD:

`kubectl get pods`

Your POD name is something like `my-service-4254283044-n9ik9`. Now setup port forwarding:

`kubectl port-forward <POD-TO-FORWARD-TO> 8083:80`

**EDIT:** Note that you need to login to google cloud from your terminal (once) before you can do  port forwarding! Here is an example, make sure to put in your zone, cluster and project: `gcloud container clusters get-credentials example-cluster --zone europe-west1-c --project example-148812`

-------- **Some Examples** --------

**Java/Spring/Ribbon**, change `application.yml` where

`account-service.ribbon.listOfServers: http://account-service`

gets replaced with

`account-service.ribbon.listOfServers: http://localhost:8081`

**Java/Feign**, change the target of the Feign/HystrixFeign builder

`HystrixFeign.builder().target(http://localhost:8081, <fallback>);`

**C#**:

```
client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:8081")
};
```

etc.

The source code modification needed can of course be done by configuration...

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up a service using [custom Endpoints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/). Normally services point to deployments, but you can make them point to specific IPs. If you set the EndPoint to your hosts' IP, services will route out of the cluster to your IDE environment. Vice versa, from your IDE you can still use services exposed via service type `LoadBalancer`.

Keep in mind that in your IDE you would miss the environment variables set by Kubernetes. I've solved this by detecting if I'm running in an IDE, and then getting what I need from the Kubernetes API. Instead of using `kubedns`, you'll have to replace the URLs by `localhosts:<port>`.

I've written a blog post on [how to setup the custom endpoints](https://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2018/03/11/local-developent-with-kubernenetes-mac-os/) which includes a working demo, if you're interested.